# Beautifulsoup4 - What is the correct way to extract text using find()?

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, findall

If I parse a website using BS4, and from its source code i want to print the text "+26.67%"

```
 <font color="green"><b><nobr>+26.67%</nobr></b></font>
```

I have been messing around with the `.find_all()` command (http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to no avail.  What would be the correct way to search the source code and print just the text?

my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    set_url = "*insert web address here*"
    set_response = requests.get(set_url)
    set_data = set_response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(set_data)
    e = soup.find("nobr")
    print(e.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

A small example:

```
>>> s="""<font color="green"><b><nobr>+26.67%</nobr></b></font>"""
>>> print s
<font color="green"><b><nobr>+26.67%</nobr></b></font>
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
>>> e = soup.find("nobr")
>>> e.text #or e.get_text()
u'+26.67%'
```

`find` return the first `Tag`, `find_all` return a `ResultSet`:

```
>>> type(e)
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
>>> es = soup.find_all("nobr")
>>> type(es)
<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>
>>> for e in es:
...     print e.get_text()
...
+26.67%
```

If you want the specified `nobr` under `b` and `font`, it can be:

```
>>> soup.find("font",{'color':'green'}).find("b").find("nobr").get_text()
u'+26.67%'
```

Continuous `.find` may cause an exception if prior `.find` returns None, pay attention.

Comment: Thats pretty much the same way I was using `find_all()`  I think the problem is the way im parsing the web page.  in your example your setting `s = """...."""` in my program im parsing the page using requests.  i'll add my code to the main question let me know what you think

Answer (score 0):

Use [a CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
>>> s = """<font color="green"><b><nobr>+26.67%</nobr></b></font>"""
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
>>> soup.select('font[color="green"] > b > nobr')
[<nobr>+26.67%</nobr>]
```

Add or remove properties or element names form the selector string to make the match more or less precise.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have my solution

```
s = """<font color="green"><b><nobr>+26.67%</nobr></b></font>"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
a = soup.select('font')
print a[0].text
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the text without using the `requests` library. Following is the edit I made to your code and it gave your expected result.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_snippet="""<font color="green"><b><nobr>+26.67%</nobr></b></font>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_snippet)
e = soup.find("nobr")
print(e.text)
```

The result was

```
+26.67%
```

Good luck!