# Extracting specific data with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, data-extraction

I want to extract a bit of data from this snippet:

```
<div id="information_content">
    <b>Name:</b> file.rar <br>
    <b>Date Modified:</b> 2 days ago <br>
    <b>Size:</b> 212.19 MB <br>
    <b>Type:</b> Archive <br>
    <b>Permissions:</b> Public </div>
</div>
```

I want to extract only `212.19 MB`.

I have extracted the snippet using `soup.find('div', attrs={'id': 'information_content'})` but I can't figure out how to drill further down to get what I need.

Can anybody help?

Comment: You can find answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21750979/beautifulsoup4-correct-way-to-use-find-all

Answer (score 0):

As BeautifulSoup doesn't support Xpath, the best way would be to use [lxml](http://lxml.de/elementsoup.html).

Answer (score 0):

If the DIV has always the same structure, you can follow this instructions, using BeautifulSoup.
Once you get the DIV extracted, create a new LIST with the text, splitted by '\n'.
Then, just select the right element of the list.

I've done something similar and here I explained everything I did:
Python and BeautifulSoup: extracting prizes from Quiniela - http://www.manejandodatos.es/2014/2/python-beautifulsoup-extracting-prizes-quiniela

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

As said previously, if the structure of these divs is always the same, the size will be in the third string if you split.

```
>>>> x = '<div id="information_content"> <b>Name:</b> file.rar <br> <b>Date Modified:</b> 2 days ago <br> <b>Size:</b> 212.19 MB <br> <b>Type:</b> Archive <br> <b>Permissions:</b> Public </div> </div>'
>>>> x.split('<br>')[2]
' <b>Size:</b> 212.19 MB '
```

From there you can use regular expressions to get just the part you need.
For example this pattern matches all values of this kind of formatting:

```
\d+.\d\d\s.B
```

it matches 10.00 kB as well as 1000.34 TB